# Adding breaks using replace()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a text input and a div that contains the same text. I'm trying to make the line breaks in the DIV text same as in the input text. So I used `.replace(/\n/g` to do this. The replace successfully identify the line breaks in the textarea and is able to add `<br>` accordingly. But the `<br>` does not do a line break, it is a part of the text string?

How do I make the `<br>` do a line break?

See example:

```
<textarea id="ab">
Test
Line breaks
on blur
</textarea>

<div id="divTx"><div>

.on("blur", ".ab", function() {
    $('#divTx').text($('#ab').val().replace(/\n/g, '<br />') );
});
```

DIV (.divTx) output:

```
Test<br> Line breaks<br>on blur<br> // <br> doesn't do line break
```

Comment: You should use `/\r\n|\r|\n/g` instead of your regex.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel thanks :) What's the reason and difference?

Comment: Different newlines, for different browsers and different operating systems. `\r\n` is for Window, `\n` for Linux and `\r` for old Macs. This way, no newline will be left behind. Or, you can use a `<pre>` instead of a `<div>`. `<pre>` elements keep the whitespace (newlines, tabs, anything!) exactly how you enter them. This saves a ton of work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`.html(htmlString)`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2)

> Set the HTML contents of each element in the set of matched elements.

*Use*

```
$('#divTx').html($('#ab').val().replace(/\n/g, '<br />'))
```

Comment: As an alternative, you can use a `<pre>`. And you might want to replace `<` and `>`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel thanks. Can you explain a bit more about the last sentence?  What are you referring by `<` and `>` ?

Comment: @Becky If you want to display as a text, you will need to replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`. Otherwise, it will be shown as HTML, and break everything if someone introduces bad html. An example would the introducing `<a` in your textarea. In text mode (using the `text` method), it won't be a problem. But in HTML, it will be all screwed up.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel. Thanks once gain. I tried this but did not work `.replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g, '&lt; br / &gt;')` ?

Comment: @Becky It should be `.replace(/[<>]/function(_){return {'<':'&lt;','>':'&gt;'}[_];}).replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g, '<br />')`. Or very similar.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: wow! I copied your line but I think there is an issue somewhere? did not work.

Comment: @Becky There is a **VERY** basic syntax error. A missing coma, fixed now: `.replace(/[<>]/,function(_){return {'<':'&lt;','>':'&gt;'}[_];}).replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g, '<br />')`

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: I think there's some issue in that as well?

Comment: @Becky God damn! The regex should be `/[<>]/g`. Sorry.

Comment: @Satpal I think it is overkill for a little experiment.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, Yea slight overkill but very well tested script, removed the comment

Comment: @Satpal I couldn't agree any more. This is just a small exercice for the O.P. She (assuming the gender based in the name) is trying the basics of regex and the likes. Pushing a little more knowledge won't harm.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: thanks.. Never expected  that I would come across something like this when I posted my question lol. thank you.

Comment: @Becky You are welcome. Here is a tiny (incomplete) playground for you: http://jsfiddle.net/mrk0cx3g/1/. It shows the effect of that replace code in the final result.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel thanks. Do you think this would server the same purpose as your suggestion? `$(this).val().split('<').join('&lt;').split('>').join('&gt;').replace(/\n/g, '<br />' )`

Comment: @Becky It would be a lot slower than a simple replace, but it would have the same effect. You can use `console.time('<timer name>'); [code] console.timeEnd('<timer name>');` to time the execution of that code. (Replace `<timer name>` with a sugestive name. The accuracy is really great on Google Chrome and Opera 12.17.)